# AppleScript copy/duplicate only newer files

Tags: copy, applescript, rsync

I have created an AppleScript that mounts a network smb share, creates folders if they don't exist then copy files to these new folders.

I am using:

```
duplicate items of folder <source> to <destination> with replacing
```

This will copy over and replace all the files. Is there a way to only duplicate newer files?

Should I be using rsync rather than duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely use rsync, with possibly the -a flag (archive option, it will work recursively along with other mirroring options, check the man page for better options for you)

```
rsync -a (source) (destination)
```

Call from applescript using the *do shell script* command, making sure you pass in posix paths.

eg,

```
set source_path to quoted form of POSIX path to source
set dest_path to quoted form of POSIX path to destination
do shell script "rsync -a " & source_path & " " & dest_path
```